# calculating the sum of the array form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator, dynamic-forms

I want to display the number of values ​​in array form. I have a lot of form with only one name is "price []" and have each value on the form. I want to calculate the total value of the form "price []". I'm still a beginner in javascript. and I want to calculate it by using javascript. The following coding that I have made.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="hitung" name="hitung">
            price 1 <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="1000"/><br>
            price 2 <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="3000"/><br>
            price 3 <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="2000"/><br>
            price 4 <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="1000"/><br>
            price 5 <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="3000"/><br><br>
            total <input type="text" name="total" class="total"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I want to ask you again, if there is a new input from the outside, then the total will also be changed directly. how to do it. help me please. thank you

Comment: don't you need a quantity to go with price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/c4UyA/1/

```
var sum = 0;
$("form > input[name='price[]']").each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    sum += parseInt($this.attr("value"));
});
$("form > input[name='total']").attr("value", sum);
```